# routerLink selected option color

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need to have red color on selected link `About`

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">About</a>
  <a routerLink="product" routerLinkActive="active">Employees</a>
</nav>
```

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `routerLinkActive`attribute receive a css class. In your case, `active` is the css class.
So you will just need to declare the class in this way in your css file:

```
.active{
   color:red;
}
```